# Made a random name generator: How to make the first letter uppercase OR lowercase randomized?

Tags: php

Disclaimer: I'm novice.

I've been making a random name generator in PHP and I'd like for it to also randomize uppercase / lowercase the first letters but haven't been able to figoure out how to do it.

I've tried everything I know so far with no luck.

```
function randomname(){
$names = array(
    'Bob',
    'Pieter',
    'Josh',
    'Dennis',
    'Charlotte',
    'Sophie',
    'Robin',
    'Renee'
);

$surnames = array(
    'Bouwer',
    'Cola',
    'Fanta',
    'Pepsi',
    'De Berg',
    'Kaas',
    'Hamburger'
);


$random = rand(0,7);
$random2 = rand(0,6);


echo ($names[$random]);

echo ($surnames[$random2]);

}


echo randomname()
```

Comment: You didn't try anything for the capitals/lower cases, why not give it a shot ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, using [`rand(0,1)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) to give a random boolean like value and [`strtolower`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to lowercase the first letter:

```
$random = rand(0,7);
$random2 = rand(0,6);

$name = $names[$random];
$surname = $surnames[$random2];

if (rand(0, 1)) $name = strtolower($name);
if (rand(0, 1)) $surname = strtolower($surname);

echo $name . ' ' . $surname;
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kIO1F)

Answer (score 0):

You can randomize the function to call to get a lower or uppercase (similar to the random name you have), like this (and you may add other function too if needed).
`array_rand` will be a better choice as you can add name or surname withouth modifying the numbers used in `rand`

```
<?php
function randomname(){
$names = [
    'Bob',
    'Pieter',
    'Josh',
    'Dennis',
    'Charlotte',
    'Sophie',
    'Robin',
    'Renee'
];

$surnames = [
    'Bouwer',
    'Cola',
    'Fanta',
    'Pepsi',
    'De Berg',
    'Kaas',
    'Hamburger'
];

$caseRandomizer = ['strtolower', 'ucfirst'];

$randomName = $names[array_rand($names)];
$randomSurname = $surnames[array_rand($surnames)];

$function = $caseRandomizer[array_rand($caseRandomizer)];

$randomName = call_user_func($function, $randomName);
$randomName = call_user_func($function, $randomSurname);

echo $randomName;
echo $randomSurname;

}


randomname();
```